# PrintThis Not Capturing Checked Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, printthis

So I am using the PrintThis JQuery plugin in order to print a form field, but for some reason I am unable to have the plugin print out any changes made to the checkboxes. When I click "Print", the only checkbox that appears to change is one that has a "checked" property by default. Any ideas on how to fix this?

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="print">
  <form>
    <input id="option" type="checkbox" checked>
    <label class="checkbox" for="option">&nbsp;&nbsp;You are 18 years or older</label>
    <br><br>
    <input id="option2" type="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox" for="option2">&nbsp;&nbsp;You have tested positive for something in your blood</label>
    <br><br>
    <input id="option3" type="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox" for="option3">&nbsp;&nbsp;You have health-related kidney problems</label>
    <br><br>
    <input id="option4" type="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox" for="option4">&nbsp;&nbsp;You have health-related skin problems</label>
    <br><br>
    <input id="option5" type="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox" for="option5">&nbsp;&nbsp;You have a low platelet count</label>
 </form>        
</div>

<br>
<br>

<input id="printButton" type="button" value="Click here to download and print this checklist to review with your doctor." />


</body>
```

> JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hybridx24/bxtpv26x/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what the problem might be here, but you can get around it by explicitly setting the checked attribute for the checkboxes that are checked.

```
$("input:button").click(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.is(':checked')) {
           $this.attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            $this.removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
    $("#print").printThis({'importStyle': true});
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bxtpv26x/17/)**

Comment: You also need to remove "checked" attribute when checkbox is unchecked

Comment: Good eye.  - printThis author

Answer (score 0):

So after skimming through the [plugin's source](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis/blob/master/printThis.js).  Looks like there's a property for form values.  I added it in and it seems to work.

`$('#selector').printThis({formValues:true});`

http://jsfiddle.net/wzp0e9r9/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the reason your version works is because I set @Susanth's answer as the base on the JSFiddle, otherwise adding `formValues` doesn't seem to make a difference.